# Display image from path in database

Tags: php, mysql, image, upload

I want to display an image I have uploaded and saved the path of the image in a MySQL database.

Below is all the code I have used to upload the image and to save the path to my table in the database:

HTML form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>


<form action="processfangstrapport.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

<table style="border-collapse: collapse; font: 12px Tahoma;" border="1" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
<tbody><tr>
<td>
<input name="billed1" type="file" accept="image/jpeg">
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<input name="Upload Now" type="submit" value="Upload Image">
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

My process php:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "fiskerirapporter";

//Opretter forbindelse til databasen
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
//Check forbindelse
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Forbindelse mislykkedes: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

    function GetImageExtension($imagetype)
     {
       if(empty($imagetype)) return false;
       switch($imagetype)
       {
           case 'image/bmp': return '.bmp';
           case 'image/gif': return '.gif';
           case 'image/jpeg': return '.jpg';
           case 'image/png': return '.png';
           default: return false;
       }
     }

if (!empty($_FILES["billed1"]["name"])) {

    $file_name=$_FILES["billed1"]["name"];
    $temp_name=$_FILES["billed1"]["tmp_name"];
    $imgtype=$_FILES["billed1"]["type"];
    $ext= GetImageExtension($imgtype);
    $imagename=date("d-m-Y")."-".time().$ext;
    $target_path = "images/".$imagename;

if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $target_path)) {

    $query_upload="INSERT into images_tbl (images_path,submission_date) VALUES 

('".$target_path."','".date("Y-m-d")."')";
    mysqli_query($conn, $query_upload) or die("error in $query_upload == ----> ".mysql_error());  

}else{

   exit("Error While uploading image on the server");
} 
echo "Din fangstrapport er nu oprettet.";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

And the structure of my database table:

```
CREATE TABLE images_tbl(
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT unique,
images_path VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
submission_date DATE
);
```

Comment: Do you get the correct path in $target_path?

Comment: Have you debugged your code to verify that all of your variables, like the path that @usermesam0023 mentioned are correct? In addition, are you getting any errors during the process, have you checked your error log?

Comment: You mean when i upload the images? The path it uploades to and the path saved in the database is the same.

Comment: I dont get any errors when i upload the images.

Comment: No matter you see any error or not, make sure that before calling move_uploaded_file(), all variables there have appropriate values.

Comment: The problem i am having is not in the code i have here, i think. My problem is that i want to display the image i have uploaded, using the path saved in my database.

Comment: Then why not simply retrieve it from the database and use it in the `src` of an image tag?

Answer (score 0):

To do this all you need to do is get the path you want from the database and use that path in an HTML image tag `src`:

```
echo '<img src="$imagePathFromDatabase" ... >';
```

To get the image from the database we just need to `SELECT` it by a query, something similar to:

```
SELECT images_path FROM images_tbl WHERE images_path='imagePathYouWant' LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Load the table data to `$result` and apply modifications to the below query according to your requirement.

```
    foreach ($result as $value){
     $path = 'http://address-upto-the-image-directory/'.$value[imagepath];
     echo "<img src='".$path."' />";
    }
```

Here `imagepath` is the field name where you stored the path in your table.